# Optional properties to filter objects by in a GET method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

Currently I have an entity **Sneaker** defined as

```
@Entity(name = "sneaker")
public class Sneaker extends Product {

    @Column
    private BigDecimal size;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column
    private BrandType brand;

    ...

    // getters, setters, constructors omitted
}
```

and a **@RestController** get method which accepts optional parameters to filter database objects depending on their properties

```
 @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<Sneaker>> getSneakers(
            @RequestParam Optional<List<BrandType>> brands,
            @RequestParam Optional<List<BigDecimal>> sizes
    ) {
        List<Sneaker> sneakers;

        if (brands.isPresent() && sizes.isEmpty()) {
            sneakers = sneakerService.getAllByBrands(Util.filterNullItems(brands.get()));
        } else if (brands.isEmpty() && sizes.isPresent()) {
            sneakers = sneakerService.getAllBySize(sizes.get());
        } else if (brands.isPresent() && sizes.isPresent()) {
            sneakers = sneakerService.getAllByBrandAndSize(brands.get(), sizes.get());
        } else {
            sneakers = sneakerService.getAll();
        }

        if (sneakers.isEmpty())
            throw new RuntimeException("No Sneakers were found");

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok(sneakers);
    }
```

What is the best practise to query the database depending on the given parameters? I'm assuming multiple *if else* statements in controller isn't the best approach as adding more properties to an object would expand my code exponentially and make a mess. Should I query all (or only by some properties) objects and filter them Java style with streams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest to use [org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html)

```
public class SneakerSpecifications {
    public static Specification<Sneaker> sizeIn(Optional<List<BigDecimal>> sizes) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> 
            sizes.isPresent() ? 
            root.get("size").in(sizes.get()) :
            builder.conjunction(); // to ignore this clause
    }

    public static Specification<Sneaker> brandIn(Optional<List<BrandType>> brands) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> 
            brands.isPresent() ? 
            root.get("brand").in(brands.get()) :
            builder.conjunction(); // to ignore this clause
    }
}
```

Then your `SneakerRepository` have to extend [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaSpecificationExecutor.html)

```
@Repository
public interface SneakerRepository 
    extends JpaRepository<Sneaker, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Sneaker> {

}
```

Your service method:

```
@Service
public class SneakerService {    

   @Autowired
   SneakerRepository repository;

    public List<Sneaker> getSneakers(Optional<List<BrandType>> brands, Optional<List<BigDecimal>> sizes) {
             Specification<Sneaker> spec = 
                 Specifications.where(SneakerSpecifications.brandIn(brands))
                 .and(SneakerSpecifications.sizeIn(sizes));

             return repository.findAll(spec);        
        }
    }
```

If you do not use `Spring Data Jpa` the same approach can be used with `Criteria API` or `Querydsl`

More information [here](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/)